# Is $B^TAB>0$ if $B>0$ and $A >0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If matrix $A$ is positive definite and matrix $B$ is positive definite, is $B^TAB$ positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For any $v\neq0$,
$$v^T(B^TAB)v=(Bv)^TA(Bv)>0$$
because $Bv\neq0$. Note that we only need that $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is non-singular.